# How to query current expanded item in accordion layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4, accordion

OK, so here is the way I can find current collapsed in accordion layout:

```as
Ext.getCmp("myaccordion").query("{collapsed}")
```

How in the same manner I can find expanded one? I can't see expanded property. Moreover, this code:

```
Ext.getCmp("myaccordion").query("not:{collapsed}")
```

crushes my browser down.

**UPD:** here is my decision, based on [example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) in ExtJS docs:

```
 Ext.ComponentQuery.pseudos.expanded = function(items) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (!items[i].collapsed) {
            res.push(items[i]);
        }   
    }   
    return res;
   };
```

And then I just query this way `Ext.getCmp("myaccordion").query(">*:expanded")`

But can we make it shorter, using `:not` somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a function for this component query.

If you have other panels somewhere in your framework that are not collapsed `query('[collapsed=false]')` would also include those so that was probably the problem you were having.

But you can limit the query to only *direct* children by calling `child` instead:

```
Ext.getCmp("myaccordion").child("[collapsed=false]");
```

Or you can limit it to direct children in the selector string itself if you give the accordion an `id` config, as it looks like you did: (`id: 'myaccordion'`). You can use:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myaccordion > panel[collapsed=false]')
```

If you have the accordion configured for only one expanded panel at a time (the default config) that will give you an array with one item - the expanded panel. If you have more than one expanded panel they will each be contained in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var p1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        title: 'Foo',
        collapsed: true
    });

    var p2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        title: 'Foo',
        collapsed: false
    });

    console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[collapsed=false]'));

});
```

Comment: does not work for me. This return something, but it definitely *not* the opposite of foo.query("{collapsed}"). I won't downvote it, since it nevertheless provide some useful information, but it would be nice if you provide some more precise answer.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can see that you can query collapsed false.